# Files resulting in dBASE table and projection file but not shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, table, dbf

Received data from an agency I'm working with. The documentation they included said what they're sending me is a *Shapefile*. When I go into *ArcCatalog* all that appears is a dbase table and project file. This is supposed to be parcel data and I was hoping maybe the dbase table had XY data or anything else I could plot, but it unfortunately does not.

Wondering if I'm doing something completely wrong (not sure what), or if they sent me the incorrect file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I...don't like the fact that it lists the .shp file as being an XML document and I wonder if that's the issue. If you'd like to send the files to me (mkennedy at esri dot com), I can see if I can open the shapefile.

Comment: @mkennedy That would be of great help. Will send it over momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML document with a .shp file type is the metadata behind the shapefile. From what it appears, you do not have all the prerequisite files for a shapefile.

Comment: You're right! The .shp file is missing, although there's a .shp.xml file.

Comment: Yep. You're right. Will contact the agency and get the correct data. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is yet an another reason to **immediately** disable the default Windows "hide known extensions" security vulnerability -- It's a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: This is also a great reason to stop using shapefiles.  File GDBs are vastly superior if you are using ArcGIS.  You can store more data, autopopulate fields, set domains, and apply rules like topology.  Also, when sending the data, there is only one .gdb file (shows as a folder in windows).